# package data and send it as form data to flask server app

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

I am attempting to make up some data with python `random` package and send it as form data using the `requests` package. Testing purposes, i am sending this to `httpbin.org` to see the responce.

sensor.py

```
import time, requests
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date, datetime
import random, json


def json_serial(obj):
    """JSON serializer for objects not serializable by default json code"""

    if isinstance(obj, (datetime, date)):
        return obj.isoformat()
    raise TypeError ("Type %s not serializable" % type(obj))


stuff = {}
stamp = json_serial(datetime.now())
elctricMeterReading = (random.random() * 440) - 15

stuff['Date'] = stamp
stuff['MeterReading'] = elctricMeterReading


print(stuff)
r = requests.post('https://httpbin.org/post', data=stuff)
#r = requests.post('http://localhost:5000/datainform', params=stuff)


print("Status code: ", r.status_code)
print("Printing Entire Post Request")
print(r.json())
```

In the response below from httpbin, I can see the `'form': {'Date': '2020-06-18T11:42:31.408767', 'MeterReading': '179.49598690916307'}` so how can I make use of this on a Flask App?

httpbin.org response:

```
Status code:  200
Printing Entire Post Request
{'args': {}, 'data': '', 'files': {}, 'form': {'Date': '2020-06-18T11:42:31.408767', 'MeterReading': '179.49598690916307'}, 'headers': {'Accept': '*/*', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Content-Length': '67', 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Host': 'httpbin.org', 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.21.0', 'X-Amzn-Trace-Id': 'Root=1-5eeb9977-4144b1b998be98a1a47d6934', 'X-B3-Parentspanid': 'a327575ce788b35a', 'X-B3-Sampled': '0', 'X-B3-Spanid': '097957453d58e94e', 'X-B3-Traceid': '101a34ed0555e0f4a327575ce788b35a', 'X-Envoy-External-Address': '207.171.103.240', 'X-Forwarded-Client-Cert': 'By=spiffe://cluster.local/ns/httpbin-istio/sa/httpbin;Hash=ea1c0e0fbd1a2a4dcfdc36e743ce618cf614b92afb4e5a6b19e7ba9a2ac7ecdb;Subject="";URI=spiffe://cluster.local/ns/istio-system/sa/istio-ingressgateway-service-account'}, 'json': None, 'origin': '207.171.103.240,10.100.91.201', 'url': 'https://httpbin.org/post'}
```

If I use sensor.py for my Flask app (comment out httpbin.org), this throws an error: `werkzeug.exceptions.HTTPException.wrap.<locals>.newcls: 400 Bad Request: KeyError: 'Date'`

Flask App code:

```
from flask import Flask, make_response, request, render_template, jsonify, make_response
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from pandas.api.types import is_string_dtype
from pandas.api.types import is_numeric_dtype
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/datainform', methods=['POST'])
def getdatatwo():

    stamp = request.form['Date']
    meterReading = request.form['MeterReading']
    #outTemp = request.form['outTemp']
    print('Date',stamp)
    print('MeterReading',meterReading)

    return 'OK', 200

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',debug=True)
```

Any tips greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

After more testing... Im not real sure why but adding this to the Flask app it seems to work just fine... `result = request.form` But code will error without it..

Here's entire script:

```
@app.route('/datainform', methods=['POST'])
def getdatatwo():

    result = request.form
    print(result)
    stamp = request.form['Date']
    meterReading = request.form['MeterReading']
    #outTemp = request.form['outTemp']
    print('Date',stamp)
    print('MeterReading',meterReading)

    return 'OK', 200

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',debug=True)
```